# Create a temp table from two tables, selecting the latest date before a specific date

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, subquery, greatest-n-per-group

I have the following two tables

**FlightTable**

```
| passenger_id | flight_date       | flight_number  | destination  | 
| -------------| ----------        | -------------- | ------------ |
| 1234         | 2020-12-16        | 534            | CA           |
| 1234         | 2020-12-29        | 876            | FL           |
| 1234         | 2020-11-13        | 938            | FL           |
| 5678         | 2020-12-27        | 986            | MN           |
| 5678         | 2020-11-19        | 347            | WA           |
```

**PassengerTable**

```
| passenger_id | company_name | phone_number   | 
| -------------| ------------ | ------------   |
| 1234         | Verizon      | (555) 874-9232 |
| 5678         | AT&T         | (555) 867-5309 |
```

I want to create a temporary table that includes specific columns from both tables, but only includes the row from **FlightTable** that has the latest flight_date occurring before 2020-12-28 for each passenger. The resulting table should look like:

**TempTable**

```
| passenger_id | company_name |flight_number  | destination  | 
| -------------| ------------ |------------   | ------------ |         
| 1234         | Verizon      |534            | CA           |
| 5678         | AT&T         |986            | MN           |
```

I've tried the following query without success:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE TempTable AS (
SELECT F.passenger_id, P.company_name, flight_number, destination
FROM FlightTable AS F, PassengerTable AS P
WHERE '2020-12-28' <= MAX(flight_date) AND F.passenger_id = P.passenger_id  
);
```

How can this be modified to work as expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, learn to use proper `JOIN` syntax.  Then you can use a correlated subquery to select the most recent date before your cutoff:

```
SELECT F.passenger_id, P.company_name, f.flight_number, f.destination
FROM FlightTable F JOIN
     PassengerTable P
     ON F.passenger_id = P.passenger_id  
WHERE f.flight_date = (SELECT MAX(f2.flight_date) 
                       FROM FlightTable f2
                       WHERE f2.passenger_id = f.passenger_id AND
                             f2.flight_date < '2012-12-28'
                      );
```

Answer (score 1):

One option uses a subquery:

```
select p.passenger_id, p.company_name, f.flight_number, f.destination
from passenger p
inner join flight f on f.passenger_id = p.passenger_id
where f.flight_date = (
    select max(f1.flight_date)
    from flight f1
    where f1.passenger_id = f.passenger_id and f1.flight_date < '2020-12-28'
)
```

Alternatively, you can use window functions:

```
select p.passenger_id, p.company_name, f.flight_number, f.destination
from passenger p
inner join (
    select f.*,
        rank() over(partition by passenger_id order by flight_date desc) rn
    from flight f
    where flight_date < '2020-12-28'
) f on f.passenger_id = p.passenger_id
where rn = 1
```